# Instead of html tag shows $$typeof : Symbol(react.element)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pushing to array edited items with html tag. But when it renders it shows $$typeof : Symbol(react.element). What i'm missing?

```
    let modalMessage="Hello, my name is /# Ann #/. I'm working for /# IStaff #/, could you please call me back"
    let arrayText = modalMessage.split("/")
    let newArray = []
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayText.length; i++) {
      newArray.push(arrayText[i])
      if (arrayText[i].includes("#")) {
        newArray.push((arrayText[i] = <input value={arrayText[i]} />))
      }
    }
    console.log(newArray.join(" "))
```

Comment: React uses JSX, not HTML, so you're seeing the internal representation of that.

Comment: Can you please add more code or any working demo by using https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/react-jsx

Comment: @MayankDudakiya https://jsfiddle.net/armakarma/cak52089/2/

Comment: @Colin how should I write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple problems here, but the main one is this:

```
newArray.join(" ")
```

`newArray` is an array that contains both strings and React elements (which are JavaScript objects, not strings of HTML). When you call `join` on it, you're telling JavaScript to (try to) turn every element into a string and then join the strings into a single string. `$$typeof : Symbol(react.element)` is the result of that attempt.

You don't need to do `join` at all. React knows how to render an array of mixed elements. You just need to return the array, though depending on your needs you might want to wrap it in e.g. `<p>` first.

Another problem in your code is that you're calling `newArray.push` but you're also assigning to `arrayText[i]`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arrayText.length; i++) {
  newArray.push(arrayText[i])
  if (arrayText[i].includes("#")) {
    newArray.push((arrayText[i] = <input value={arrayText[i]} />))
  }
}
```

You should pick one, e.g.:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arrayText.length; i++) {
  if (arrayText[i].includes("#")) {
    arrayText[i] = <input value={arrayText[i]} />;
  }
}
```

This will replace the elements that have `#` in them with `<input>`s while leaving the other elements intact. Here's a demo of it working:

```js
 
const App = ({ modalMessage }) => {
  const arrayText = modalMessage.split("/");

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayText.length; i++) {
    if (arrayText[i].includes("#")) {
      arrayText[i] = <input value={arrayText[i]} />;
    }
  }

  return <p>{arrayText}</p>;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App modalMessage="Hello, my name is /# Ann #/. I'm working for /# IStaff #/, could you please call me back" />,
  document.querySelector("div")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

However, a more idiomatic version would use `map`:

```
const App = ({ modalMessage }) => (
  <p>
    {modalMessage
      .split("/")
      .map(text => (text.includes("#") ? <input value={text} /> : text))}
  </p>
);
```

Comment: How to leave '/' ? I need to save  string with new values and send it back to server.  Later  backend reads new values only if there /# some text #/ . Right now there is no  "/". Or even display values without "/#" and after saving add "/#"